# Animating UIImageView with mask (Core Animations with masks)

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I have one UIImage in UIImageView (object on image). It needs to be animated to the right, but this animation needs to be masked with this circle mask.
[image]

My current code is:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, 44, 44, 21, 0, 2 * M_PI, NO);

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
[shapeLayer setPath:path];
[shapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[shapeLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
[shapeLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

UIImageView *loadingShape = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6.5, 7.5, 89, 40)];
[loadingShape setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"object_image.png"]];
[self addSubview:loadingShape];
// Set the mask for the image view's layer
[[loadingShape layer] setMask:shapeLayer];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
[loadingShape setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 7.5, 89, 40)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But this animates my whole UIImageView masked. I need mask to be static, just object behind to be animated.

What is the best solution to make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Kurt, I refined a little bit my code and got what I wanter :)

> CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
>
> ```
> CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, 44, 44, 21, 0, 2 * M_PI, NO);
>
> CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
> [shapeLayer setPath:path];
> [shapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
> [shapeLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
> [shapeLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
>
> UIView *loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6.5, 7.5, 44, 44)];
>
> UIImageView *loadingShape = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 18, 89, 40)];
> [loadingShape setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"object_image.png"]];
> [[loadingView layer] setMask:shapeLayer];
> [loadingView addSubview:loadingShape];
> [self addSubview:loadingView];
> // Set the mask for the image view's layer
>
> CABasicAnimation* anim = [[CABasicAnimation alloc] init];
> anim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 18)];
> anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(15, 18)];
> anim.keyPath = @"position";
> anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:@"linear"];
> anim.duration = 0.3;
> anim.repeatCount = 100000;
> [[loadingShape layer] addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
> ```

Comment: You are animating `position` but giving it `fromValue` and `toValue` which are `CGRect`s. Shouldn't they be `CGPoints`?

Comment: You are right, I changed in code. But both solutions works :)

Answer (score 4):

The mask layer `shapeLayer` acts as though it is a child of the other layer `[loadingShape layer]`. When the parent layer moves, the child moves with it.

In addition to your current animation, you will have to animate `shapeLayer`, in the opposite direction.

**Edit:** The animation established by `-[UIView beginAnimations:context:]` does not automatically apply to a bare `CALayer`, so set up the animation manually.

```
CGPoint p = /* you decide the new position of the shapeLayer */;
CABasicAnimation* anim = [[CABasicAnimation alloc] init];
anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p];
anim.keyPath = @"position";
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:@"easeOut"];
anim.duration = 0.3;
anim.repeatCount = 10;
[shapeLayer.mask addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
[anim release];
```

Comment: Hmm, tried to do this by animating position of the layer and bounds, but without success :|
Can you show me with some snippet?

Comment: You should be able to do this by animating `shapeLayer`'s position. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: I'm guessing that you expected the `UIView` animation parameters to automatically apply to the CALayer. They don't. I added some code to the answer.